# sorting list with key parameter of letter 'x'

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting

So fo example I have a list input. And I want to RETURN a list, sorted at first by letter 'x' and then alphabetically. I'm very new in Python and currently doing google's python class.

So input: `['abc', 'bad', 'xzx', 'xxy']`

And expected return is: `['xxy', 'xzx', 'abc', 'bad']`.

What I've already tried:

- To create a new function that would look for every 'x' letter in list, but failed this one;
- To use key function in sorted failed too :(

Comment: What about `['vas', 'acg', 'bxd']` - do you want `'bxd'` first because it has an x, or is it just "alphabetical except as if the alphabet starts with x"?

Comment: if that's the case, the answer you accepted is wrong, since it would sort `bxd` before `bad`

Comment: If you expect it to do what you described, it won't work in all situations. That's different from it having an arbitrary side effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little key function trickery:

```
>>> l = ['abc', 'bad', 'xzx', 'xxy']
>>> k = lambda c: -1 if c == 'x' else ord(c)
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda s: [k(c) for c in s])
['xxy', 'xzx', 'abc', 'bad']
```

Function `k` returns `-1` when applied to `'x'` and and the unicode point of any other character ([`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord)). Since these unicode points (integers) mirror the chars' lexicographic order and are guaranteed to be greater or equal to `0`, this ensures that `'x'` will have the lowest value.

The key function in the sort then [comprehends](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) each string into a list of `k(c)` for each char `c` in the string.

Comment: Added some explanation and links.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort with a `key` that replaces every `x` with a character that is "smaller" than any alphabetic character: (like `'0'`)

```
>>> lst = ['abc', 'bad', 'xzx', 'xxy']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x.replace('x', '0'))
['xxy', 'xzx', 'abc', 'bad']
```

If you only want to have the strings that start with `x` in front:

```
>>> lst = ['abc', 'bad', 'xzx', 'xxy']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x[0] != 'x', x))
['xxy', 'xzx', 'abc', 'bad']
```

Comment: But there might be more than one 'x'.

Comment: This would sort alphabetically from the second letter on. I think the 'x' should be preferred at each position. e.g. yours produces `['bad', 'xcx', 'xxy']` where `'xcx'` comes before `'xxy'`.

Comment: okay, then I misunderstood "at first by letter 'x' and then alphabetically". I've updated the answer.

Comment: You could do `x.replace('x', chr(0))` to really get the lowest possible char. But that would still not prefer `x` over said char.

Comment: but it's really fast and works as long as the strings only contain alphabetical characters (and that was more or less the assumption of the question).